# get first, second and third date of each file opened - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this code to group by col1 to get the nsmallest dates in order of the times the file was opened but it seems to come in random order but that is what I don't need.
Here is my code.

```
data=(df.groupby(['col1']).date
   .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.value_counts()
                               .nsmallest(3).index))
   .unstack(level=1).fillna(0).astype(str))
```

output:

```
  col1              0                                1                          2
  file 1    2020-05-07 09:52:44.502     2020-05-06 04:53:32.449     2020-05-18 06:12:27.872
  file 2    2020-05-08 09:02:44.502     2020-05-04 04:53:32.449     2020-05-19 06:12:27.872
```

The output that I want:

```
       col1                 0                                1                          2
      file 1   2020-05-06 04:53:32.449  2020-05-07 09:52:44.502     2020-05-18 06:12:27.872
      file 2    2020-05-04 04:53:32.449 2020-05-08 09:02:44.502     2020-05-19 06:12:27.872
```

DATA:

```
'{"col1":{"0":"file1","1":"file2","2":"file3","3":"file","4":"file1","5":"file2","6":"file3","7":"file4","8":"file3","9":"file1"},"date":{"0":"2020-05-01 00:38:38.154","1":"2020-05-01 00:38:53.904","2":"2020-05-01 00:43:52.487","3":"2020-05-01 03:35:40.399","4":"2020-05-01 04:19:32.615","5":"2020-05-01 04:22:15.545","6":"2020-05-01 04:22:47.439","7":"2020-05-01 04:23:48.706","8":"2020-05-01 04:25:26.140","9":"2020-05-01 04:28:36.257"}}'
```

btw, the date is string format and I cannot convert it to datetime because I need to concat a string to each date in the next stage for some differentitation.

Please help, how can I get the output in the desired order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
df['count'] = df.sort_values('date').groupby('col1').cumcount()

df.set_index(['col1', 'count']).query('count <= 2')['date'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
count                        0                        1                        2
col1                                                                            
file   2020-05-01 03:35:40.399                      NaN                      NaN
file1  2020-05-01 00:38:38.154  2020-05-01 04:19:32.615  2020-05-01 04:28:36.257
file2  2020-05-01 00:38:53.904  2020-05-01 04:22:15.545                      NaN
file3  2020-05-01 00:43:52.487  2020-05-01 04:22:47.439  2020-05-01 04:25:26.140
file4  2020-05-01 04:23:48.706                      NaN                      NaN
```

Comment: I ran your code but the first row my dataset itself is unordered. 
2020-05-18 06:12:27.872 , 2020-05-16 12:42:03.010 ,        2020-05-07 09:52:44.502

Comment: third row output - 2020-06-03 09:14:59.871 , 2020-05-29 08:00:50.162

Comment: Sorry.. that should have been `sort_values('date')`.  I modified the code.

Comment: Yes, Yes. I just made that modification from my side and it worked. Awesome, Thanks.